# Use Z3 in multicore server

Tags: c++, multithreading, z3, multicore

I want to set up a system that will be fully dedicated to Z3. Let's say it has 4 cores and I would like to use all the power of the machine.

I will be solving large formulas that have around 1000 incremental asserts.

I would like to solve the formulas in a parallel fashion. I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828612/solving-formulas-in-parallel-with-z3) and I see that a unique `Context` should be created for every instance solving a formula.

My question then is, what is the most optimal way to use the full system resources (4 cores) and solving formulas with incremental asserts? Should I create a context per core and somehow sync the push and pops along them to incrementally solve the formulas?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a "most optimal" way, it really depends on the problems you're trying to solve. If you're using the API you have to use separate contexts for every thread/process. I don't think there's a good reason for having more than one context per thread/process.

Comment: So you would create a Context per core? Will each context use a different core? Since there will be 1000 asserts that will be incrementally solved having 4 Contexts means having duplicated information 4 times (1 per core). I that right? Is there a better way to do it than just having every assert in every Context? Thank you @ChristophWintersteiger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions created via one context can not be used in another context. So, yes, if those cores/contexts need the same expressions, they will have to be copied and/or translated (see also [Z3_translate](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#ga9034ab0dbfff188e15a02421488ea8cf)).